# Issue with Maven Project in Jenkins CI server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Now we are trying to deploy maven project by using the Jenkins CI tool.

I have created a sample maven  project and added the repository URL and credentials of my local repository then i have clicked on the Build Job .
then Jenkins downloaded my code into the work space of the particular job and its downloaded all the dependencies  but i got the following error in the Jenkins console output as shown in the below.

```
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar (61 KB at 31.6 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar (228 KB at 74.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar (425 KB at 42.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.bodar.com/com/googlecode/totallylazy/totallylazy/1.20/totallylazy-1.20.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.bodar.com/com/googlecode/totallylazy/totallylazy/1.20/totallylazy-1.20.jar (949 KB at 718.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:00.677s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 20 01:44:31 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/22M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gcrtesting: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.vidyayug.testing:gcrtesting:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven testing selenium/pom.xml to com.vidyayug.testing/gcrtesting/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/gcrtesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can any one help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's searching for a oracle-specific library and you're using open jdk. Switching to Oracle jdk will probably fix your issue.

Install Oracle jdk in your Jenkins server and point JAVA_HOME/PATH variables to Oracle jdk.

Comment: Thanks Amila . The issue got resolved when added oracle Java home  to that particular job in jenkins then maven build -successful but in my maven  project has selenium script for automate the testing process while running the script through the Jenkins it needs to open firefox browser at that time i got the following error
##Running se.thinkcode.itake.RunCukesTest
Feature: MyGcr
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Answer (score 0):

Check in cmd (or shell, depends on your OS) your java version

```
java -version
```

and the path

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

You're probably using jre instead of jdk.